# FreeRTOS xPortStartScheduler does not clear BASEPRI

Tags: freertos

Trying to run FreeRTOS on ESP32 ARM Cortex M4F, but it fails inside xPortStartScheduler.

```
static void prvPortStartFirstTask( void )
{
/* Start the first task.  This also clears the bit that indicates the FPU is
 * in use in case the FPU was used before the scheduler was started - which
 * would otherwise result in the unnecessary leaving of space in the SVC stack
 * for lazy saving of FPU registers. */
__asm volatile (
    " ldr r0, =0xE000ED08   \n"/* Use the NVIC offset register to locate the stack. */
    " ldr r0, [r0]          \n"
    " ldr r0, [r0]          \n"
    " msr msp, r0           \n"/* Set the msp back to the start of the stack. */
    " mov r0, #0            \n"
    " msr control, r0       \n"
    " cpsie i               \n"/* Globally enable interrupts. */
    " cpsie f               \n"
    " dsb                   \n"
    " isb                   \n"
    " svc 0                 \n"/* System call to start first task. */
    " nop                   \n"
    " .ltorg                \n"
    );
    }
```

The call to "svc 0" will fail because the BASEPRI is not zero.

When calling xTaskCreate() BASEPRI is set to configMAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY and this is done before starting the scheduler. Should be ok.

I tried manually setting BASEPRI to 0 and this seems to fix the issue, but I have been using FreeRTOS in the past, and never had to do this "fix".

So to sum up:

```
Init_stuff..
xTaskCreate(..);  // Sets BASEPRI = 0xA0 (configMAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY)
vTaskStartScheduler();
-> xPortStartScheduler(...)
   -> prvPortStartFirstTask() // svc 0 fails because BASEPRI=0xA0
```

I'm guessing there is something important that I'm missing, where is BASEPRI suppose to be restored to zero ?

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by the SVC prio not being zero.